# WPF Displaying malayalam in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF app to extract title bar from a webpage (language is in Malayalam) and display on a textBlock.
the problem am facing is on displaying the text (the Malayalam letters) are replaced with questions marks/registered logo sort of charterers.

how do i render malayalam font correctly in the WPF textBlock or a textbox ?

here is the XAML code for TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Name="media" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

here is the code for **scraping** the data from a site

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    var read = client.OpenRead(url);
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(read);
    var title = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText;
    string text = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

    media.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        media.Text = title + Environment.NewLine;
    });
}
```

[image: The Result i get]

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem is not displaying the text in TextBlock, but getting it from the server. You should load the document with proper encoding, something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadData(url);
var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); //use proper encoding
```

Or try using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: i am using HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: So try downloading/loading data in proper encoding. Encoding is probably the case.

Comment: hey sorry, for being too late to reply to this comment, i have created a function to do as u said and it is actually working good.
only problem now am facing is with some charecters.
some charecters in this text " കുമ്പളാംപൊയ്ക സര്&#x200d;വീസ് സഹകരണ ബാങ്കില്&#x200d; താമസമാക്കിയ കുടുംബം ഇന്ന് സമരം അവസാനിപ്പിച്ചു " 
gets replaced automatically in the downloaded data.
how to fix this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets replaced"? Replaced by what?

Comment: i used UTF8 which is actually the correct encoding ( only one which displays the text  partially) 
but some letters are getting replaced with #x200d;
for example in this text = സര്&#x200d;വീസ്
i used breakpoints and the downloaded data " var data " has the problem itself.
the downloaded data is incorrect with these replacements.